# How to query custom post type by a relationship field value

Tags: php, wordpress

Why querying a page based on the perma-link of a post gives me an error:

```
foreach ($serv as $servi) : //$serv is my array
    $the_id = $servi->ID; // 94093
    $get_perma_basename = basename(get_permalink($the_id)); //http://www.mywes.com/serv/my-page -> my-page
    $get_prov = get_posts(array(
         'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
         'meta_query' => array(
          array(
                'key' => 'serv', // name of the relationship field in all post with the custom post type
                'value' => '"' . get_perma_basename . '"', //compare to see which entry in my custom post type has the `my-page` value
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                )
            ));
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant get_perma_basename - assumed 'get_perma_basename' in /var/www/my_site/check-for-page.php on line 310
```

Line `310` is `'value' => '"' . get_perma_basename . '"'`

How can I resolve the issue so it can query correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$get_perma_basename` (variable) instead of `get_perma_basename` (constant).